# Birt Report parameter validation

Tags: validation, birt

`NewParameter` is of type `DATE` and having Custom Format as `MM/dd/yyyy` in parameter window.

I have written the following code to verify whether the user is sending correct format or not. If user sends `24/12/2014` the code should throw error as `Invalid format`. But the following code is throwing the error even while user send the correct format e.g: `11/10/2014`

```
importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
importPackage(Packages.java.text);

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");  
testDate = null;
dateerror=false;

try  {  
    testDate = sdf.parse(params["NewParameter"]);  
    dataerror=false;
} catch (e) {
    errorMessage = "the date you provided is in an invalid date";  
    eee = e;
    dateerror=true; 
    reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("mytable").drop();
}
```

Comment: Removed the function for parsing the date parameter NewParameter.Declared NewParameter as Date data type and has CustomFormat as MM/dd/yyyy and given  value for NewParameter as 111/122/2014 But Birt is not able to throw the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a confusion: when we declare a report parameter as "DATE", we don't have to parse it in report scripts because it is already a java Date object. Therefore this line of code is wrong, because the parser would expect a "String" type:

```
testDate = sdf.parse(params["NewParameter"]);
```

The custom format "MM/dd/yyyy" you linked to the report parameter is not actually used by the report engine: it is only taken into consideration by the webviewer, to specify how dates should be displayed in parameters dialog.

The best way to achieve your requirements would be to customize client-side javascript of your webviewer, in order to control date format in web-browsers. An example of this approach allows to enter dates through a calendar such [here](http://www.visioneo.org/external-datepickers).

Otherwise if you really need to validate a format during report execution, although it is not very elegant the only way would be to set your parameter as "String" type and put your script in "Initialize" event of the report. However in this case you would have to parse it each time it is used in a dataset, or parse it once in a report variable.

Comment: Hi I made NewParameter  as String type and verified and tested  case 1: 12/01/2014 its displaying its the correct format(the date you provided is in an valid date).                               Case 2:12-01-2014 its displaying incorrect format(the date you provided is in an invalid date).                                 Case 3:122/100/20140 its showing as correct format date(the date you provided is in an valid date).But in case 3 its not a correct date as u see.Birt script is not handling parse of the date function in right way.how to handle this.